# Awkward spacing betwen words in HTML

Tags: html, css

The text on my webpage has the following awkward spacing problem:

[image: Resulting HTML]

It is in asp.net. I have tried the following:

**CSS**

```
.optionClosed
        {
            font-size: large;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#004C7E;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="0px" width="50%" style="float:left; display:inline-table;" >
     <tr id="optCloseMessage" runat="server"  align="justify" style="display:none;">
        <td>                                    
           <span class="optionClosed">  An option has already been selected for this month. If you would like to make further changes to your account, please cancel your pending option</span>                                         
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I have also tried replacing `<span>` with a `<p>` tag and also not including any tags and just using `<td class="optionClosed">`

Is there a way to get rid of the spacing problem or some insight into what I am setting up incorrectly? Thanks.

Comment: `align="justify"`... take that out.

Comment: To expand what @MarcB said. Justify will alter the spacing so that the text will fill the line (unless a newline is encountered).  By setting it to justify, you are making the spacing inconsistent.

Comment: Oh wow. That did it. Thanks to both of you. I didn't know that about justify. @MarcB please make an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`align="justify"` ... take that out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove `align="justify"` from your html